# What is the term for a collection of chiral molecules of unequal amounts of left- and right-handed enantiomers?

Tags: terminology

This is what I found on wiki:

> In chemistry, a racemic mixture, is one that has equal amounts of left- and right-handed enantiomers of a chiral molecule.

> Homochirality can also refer to enantiopure substances in which all the constituents are the same enantiomer ...

But what is the term for a collection of chiral molecules of **not exactly** the equal amounts of left- and right-handed enantiomers?

Comment: ‘Scalemic’ mixture was used in older literature to describe a non 1:1 mix of enantiomers. Not seen so much now days, presumably as much easier to quantify the exact e.e/e.r

Comment: There is no specific word, but we can describe something called as *enantiomeric excess.* Search this term.

Comment: I would say simply "optically active".

Comment: "Rotatory", but without specifying the direction if unknown...